# Проверить статус загрузки аудио у всех элементов документа

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ol>
    <li>
    <span>Не готов</span>
        <audio src="TRACK" preload="metadata"></audio>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>Не готов</span>
        <audio src="TRACK" preload="metadata"></audio>
    </li>
</ol>
```

На страницe находится несколько `ol`. Это плейлисты. У них нет ни идентификаторов, ни классов.

Как пройтись циклом по всем `ol` их `li`, проверить состояние всех audio, которые в них находятся используя `readyState` и если оно равно **4**, то заменить текст в этом `li span` на  `готов`?

Учитывая то, что плейлисты могут создаваться динамически, то проходить циклом нужно будет ежесекундно. Если это будет вызывать нагрузку, то буду проверять динамические плейлисты отдельно.

Пробую так. Возвращает **undefined**

```
$('ol li').find('audio').each(function() {
  console.info($(this).readyState);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` возвращает враппер над дом элементом, а не сам элемент. а вот this внутри функции указывает на сам элемент:

```js
$('ol li').find('audio').each(function() {
  console.info(this.readyState);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
    <li>
    <span>Не готов</span>
        <audio src="TRACK" preload="metadata"></audio>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>Не готов</span>
        <audio src="TRACK" preload="metadata"></audio>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Если `$(this)` это `ol li`, тогда я не могу понять почему я не могу получить доступ к `span` используя  `$(this).find('span').text('Готово');`

Comment: @ДенисНебесный это `<audio>`

Comment: А как получить доступ к span?

Comment: `$('ol li').find('span')`?

Comment: Ну я ведь выше написал, что это из цикла получить не удается

Comment: или $(this).parents('li').find('span').addClass('nameClass');

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо)

Comment: @ДенисНебесный а я не понял что из цикла, `$( this ).prev()`